# Writing to temp file and reading the same values to from another script in python

Tags: file, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to write the intermediate values like progress in file and read the values from  another script to update the same in some tool in python i.e. writing to temp file from one script and reading it from another script. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you want to start by yourself and then ask a more specific question.

Comment: (1) why do you want to write to a file and not e.g., to a pipe? What is the context? (2) Why do you need a subprocess here? Do you want to run a child Python script from within your parent Python script? Consider importing the module and using its functions instead. (3) Do you know how to write to a file in Python? Create [mcve]

Comment: let me explain the scenario: i need to generate the progress values and write it to temp file using sub process, then using one more script(i.e. wrapper script) will be reading the values from the temp file and call some tool API to display the progress values. Basically writing to a file is happening from one script with the help of sub process and reading is happening from one more wrapper script. And Progress is update from after each iteration. Please revert if still there is a doubt.